# Child MDI Form appears below the parent MDI control

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild

I have 2 Forms; Form1 and Form2. In Form1, there's a MenuStrip and a button. When I click the button, Form2 appears below the Form1 button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.MdiParent = this;
    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm.Show();
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Any control you put on the MDI parent form *must* be docked to an edge.  If they are not then they'll always overlap an MDI client window.  You'd normally dock a panel and put any controls you need on that panel.  Just a single button ought to be a menu item instead.

Answer (score 3):

Child forms in an MDI container always underlay other controls that are directly placed on the MDI container:

[image]

You'll see the same behavior if you move the Form underneath your menu too, although since the MenuStrip is docked, you should see scroll bars that allow you to view the entire Form.

[image]

Either merge your button onto the MenuStrip:

[image]

Or dock it to an edge somewhere: *(this looks ridiculous, but it's just to demonstrate; you could dock a panel and move it in there, or play around with a ToolStrip, for example)*

[image]

Comment: sir give me some advise that i want to visible menustrip in all form but other control is behind the open form

Comment: I would set button on the middle it`s for just testing purpose....actually in the middle I have registration page but when I open new form the page is behind all controls..so guide me to solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

When you set `IsMdiContainer` to `true`. The form automatically adds [System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mdiclient) into `ParentForm.Controls`. It usually adds after all docked controls are added. So that, It appears below the button. You can undock this MDI container. You can customize it. It's only possible in the code. Like:-

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    if (control is MdiClient mdic)
    {
        mdic.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        mdic.Bounds = new(50, 50, 200, 200);
        //You can use Size & Location instead.
    }
}
```

In this way, you can't change the background of the parent form. But you can do if you add this MDI container manually. Then, you can't set `Form.MdiParent` to `ParentForm`. You've to write it manually. Like:-

```
MdiClient mdic = new MdiClient();
ParentForm.Controls.Add(mdic);
//Customize your MdiClient in this line
mdiClient.Controls.Add(ChildForm);
```